# C# Selenium testing with MS Edge driver

Tags: c#, selenium, microsoft-edge

I am using C#, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting and Selenium to test a website.

I know MS Edge is no longer being developed, and is being replaced with a Chromium-based product.  In the interim, I would still like to be able to tell my customers that Edge is a supported browser until the replacement occurs.

But it looks like using the selenium EdgeDriver requires a valid microsoftwebdriver - and the latest one is not compatible with the latest version of Windows - my machine uses Windows 10 Version 1809 / build 17763.379.

Has anyone been able to get Edge testing to work with Selenium on a Windows 10 build 1809 machine?  If so, please show some sample code and needed steps / references / usings / etc.

If seen a few posting about this where some responses say it is impossible, and others say it is possible - but the ones that say it is possible don't show any actual code or reference names.

Comment: Not sure about C#, but I am tried Python and Ruby successfully on my windows 10 machine. Let me know if you have any questions, how I am doing it on Python, ruby (btw I did not started working with RemoteDriver at).

Comment: Successfully completed the Grid implementation with Edge. Let me know if you need the details, how I configured the node and the launched the Edge.

Comment: You could check [this article](https://www.automatetheplanet.com/microsoft-edge-webdriver-what-everybody-ought-know-about/) to use Edge WebDriver

Comment: supputuri - yes - i would like to see how you did it. 
With chrome and Firefox a line like this instantiates the driver: IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
With Edge, based on the old documentation, this will work as long as the Microsoft Edge WebDriver is installed - but there is no compatible webdriver for Win 10 Version 1809 / build 17763.379.

Comment: Zhi Lv - thanks - but that article is not current and the steps cannot be followed due to the webdriver problem noted above.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/edge-selenium-tools - NuGet package - Microsoft.Edge.SeleniumTools can be used to get it implemented.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install edge driver version equal to the version of edge in your system. To find edge version number go to settings->about microsoft edge .Download the correct version from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver After downloading you need to change the name of driver to MicrosoftWebDriver.exe from msedgedriver.exe. Then It will work :)

Answer (score 1):

I apologize to any readers that I didn't post the solution I eventually found - which is quite simple.  Here's the code of instantiating the driver:

```
      var service = OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\Drivers", @"msedgedriver.exe");
                    service.UseVerboseLogging = true;
                    service.UseSpecCompliantProtocol = true;
                    service.Start();

                    var options = new OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeOptions();
                    // For future reference - please check to see if there are options that should be set...

                    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.ServiceUrl, options);
```

As you can see, I keep the latest edge driver in a dircetory called "C:\Drivers".  The latest driver can always be downloaded from the selenium website downloads page (https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/) - expand the Browsers section on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Sample C# Code

```
        else if (AppSettings.Browser == "Edge")
        {
            EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions()
            {
                UseInPrivateBrowsing = true,
            };
            driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions);
        }
```

and Remove all Nuget references to MicrosoftDriver, Clean the Solution
Then Run the below command in CMD Admin mode

**DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0**

Note: This Solution is for Microsoft Edge version 18 or Above

Answer (score 0):

Well after a long time navigating the internet found a solution for that!

At least you have to remove your NuGet package WebDriver(actual version) and install the beta version, then go to this website https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/4.0.0-beta2 copy the beta nuget you want in my case 4.0.0 till the moment, then open your visual studio (mine is 2019) Tools>Nuget Package Manager>Package Manger Console here you paste your copy.
*Ps. make download from edge chromium*

```cs
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;
public class Example Edger
{
    private IWebDriver driver;
                     
    public void SetupTest()
    {
        driver = new EdgeDriver();
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    }
}
```